# Puppeteer Page Object Model with browser and page put apart from main

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, puppeteer

I'm trying to put in a class the puppeter call, the browser object, and the page object. But I'm being unable to use it when using the Page Object Model. Page members are undefined.

In every example that I've found I always seen the call to puppeteer and the browser and page object within the main function. I guess that's a problem with context access.

But it's possible to archieve what I'm looking for and still be able to use at least the page object within Page Object files ?

**main.mjs**

```
import Browser from './browser.mjs'
import HomePage from './HomePage.mjs'

async function main () {
    const browser = new Browser();
    const homePage = new HomePage(browser.page);
    await homePage.open();
    console.log(await homepage.getTitle());
    await browser.close();
}
main();
```

**browser.mjs**

```
class Browser {
    constructor() {
        return this.main(); // I know, that's ugly
    }

    async main() {
        this.browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: false,
        });

        this.page = await browser.newPage();
        return this.browser,this.page
    }
}

export default Browser
```

**homepage.mjs**

```
class HomePage {
    constructor(page) {
        this.page = page;
    }

    async open() {
        this.page.goto('http://www.contoso.com');
    }

    async getTitle() {
        return this.page.title();
    }
}

export default HomePage
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return this.browser,this.page
```

This returns the `browser`. If you want to access browser and page, you should return `this` only. Your code should look like below.

```
return this
```

You can access browser, page and everything between from that object.

Comment: It's also returning undefined browser / page objects.

Comment: `await new Browser();` use await.

Comment: I also see another typo `New` should be `new`.

Comment: The `New` typo was an error writing the question only. It was correct in the actual code. It worked adding the await, and changing the return. Thanks sir.